# How to make indy server and client listen for data on separate thread in c++ not Delphi

Tags: multithreading, sockets, c++builder, indy10

I am using c++ builder XE8, and I am just a beginner. I don't know anything about Delphi. To listen for incoming data on server and client both end, I inserted `Thread Object` from `Flie->New->Other->C++ builder Files` (as I saw in a video demo of threading), and named it TSocketThreard.

On the client end I assign the client socket to a TIdIOHandlerSocket var (fsock) and used the following code to listen continuously for imcoming data.
len is int, s is String var and lbox is a TListBox.

```
void __fastcall TSocketThread::Execute()
{
    FreeOnTerminate = True;
    while(1){
        if (Form1->fsock != NULL && Form1->fsock->Connected()) {
            if(Form1->fsock->CheckForDataOnSource(10))
                Form1->len = Form1->fsock->ReadLongInt();
                Form1->s = Form1->fsock->ReadString(Form1->len);
                Form1->lbox->Items->Add(Form1->s);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to start it from client's onConnect event and from a button(I use to connect the client to server) also. But both times its got freeze.

On the server end I tried to OnExecute event on the same way. I mean, at first assigned socket to a var, put the code like above on a thread's(which I inserted like before) execute method, and started the thread's start() method from onExecute event.For the server I want to make it work on asynchronous mode (to handle at least few hundreds clients).

I can feel I am doing it the wrong way, but its really hard to find a good example in c++. Please some one show me the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy servers are already multi-threaded, you don't need to create your own reading threads. The `TIdTCPServer::OnExecute` event runs in a thread, and each client has its own thread. Just use the socket that the event gives you, don't use your own variable.

```
void __fastcall TMyServerForm::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    // use AContext->Connection->IOHandler as needed...
}
```

On the client side, your reading thread is doing things that are not thread-safe, which can lead to UI freezing, amongst other problems.  Try something more like this instead:

```
class TSocketThread : public TThread
{
private:
    TIdIOHandler *fIOHandler;
    String fString;
    void __fastcall UpdateListBox();
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall Execute();
public
    __fastcall TSocketThread(TIdIOHandler *AIOHandler);
};

__fastcall TSocketThread::TSocketThread(TIdIOHandler *AIOHandler)
    : TThread(false), fIOHandler(AIOHandler)
{
}

void __fastcall TSocketThread::Execute()
{
    while (!Terminated)
    {
        int len = fIOHandler->ReadLongInt();
        fString = fIOHandler->ReadString(len);
        Synchronize(&UpdateListBox);
    }
}

void __fastcall TSocketThread::UpdateListBox()
{
    Form1->lbox->Items->Add(fString);
}
```

```
TSocketThread *Thread = NULL;

void __fastcall TMyClientForm::IdTCPClient1Connected(TObject *Sender)
{
    Thread = new TSocketThread(IdTCPClient1->IOHandler);
}

void __fastcall TMyClientForm::IdTCPClient1Disconnected(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (!Thread) return;
    Thread->Terminate();
    if (!IsCurrentThread(Thread))
    {
        Thread->WaitFor();
        delete Thread;
        Thread = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much @Remy Sir, I couldn't reply on time, bcoz I was little bit sick. I'll try it now, and I am really greatfull to you Sir. I have just one question regarding indy server, that is if it is already multi threaded will the response  coming from one client interrupt/pause the processing of response from another client, if both of them reached to the server at the same time?

Comment: sir, one more thing when I try your code its showing `unknown type name 'TIdIOHandler'` error. Do I have to include any extra header file for this?

Comment: Oh I have figured out the answer `#include <IdTCPConnection.hpp>` .

Comment: `TIdIOHandler` is declared in `IdIOHandler.hpp`, which is `#include`'d by `IdTCPConnection.hpp`. Most Indy classes/components are implemented in their own units.

Comment: Hmm I got it. Thank you very much @Remy Lebeau Sir. One more thing sir, sometime when i send some text from client to server, its not showing at that time (I use ListBox to show text). when I send any second text it's showing both (the current and the prev text). Why such thing is happening sir, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I can't answer that since you have not shown any of your server code yet. Are you synchronizing with the main UI thread when updating the ListBox?

Comment: `void __fastcall TForm1::on_connect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
 label1->Text = "Client connected";
}`  `void __fastcall TForm1::on_disconnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
   label1->Text = "Client disconnected";
}``void __fastcall TForm1::on_execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
  int len = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLongInt();
  String s = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadString(len);
 ListBox1->Items->Add(s);
}` Thats all my code. I did nothing extra @Remy Sir.

Comment: You are not synchronizing with the main UI thread when accessing the Label and ListBox controls.

Comment: Sir, I have added another .cpp file, with the code`class MyNotify:public TIdNotify{protected: String msg; virtual void __fastcall DoNotify(){ Form1->ListBox->Items->Add(msg);} public: __fastcall MyNotify(const String &tmp):TIdNotify(), msg(tmp) };` and inside `on_execute` I have put `(new MyNotify(s))->Notify();` (here is s String var). Now its working fine. I have found this from one of your answer. I hope I didn't do anything, which can cause any problem for my program in future.